# jetty 9 jsp not loading which are in webapp folder

Tags: jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I am quite new to jetty. The current project uses embedded jetty. Currently, for each change even in the front end we have build the project to a war, stop currently running jetty project, and start the server in new build.

As it's taking too long, I thought I should try and start the embedded jetty once from eclipse and making a code change should apply directly in the output. I am trying to run my project from eclipse using eclipse jetty plugin.

I almost got it to work. It loads the .jsp pages in WEB-INF and it also loads css and js in webapp folder.

However, the current front end is written in such a way that they have templates for each page in a '.jsp' file which are also in webapp folder, which are called using commonjs in the following way

```
<body class="container">
<input type="text" id="csrfId" value="${fn:escapeXml(sessionScope.userBean.userToken)}" class="hidden">
<main>
</main>
<div id="spinner" class="disablepopUp"></div>
<div id="modalOverlay"></div>
<script src="common/lib/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require([ 'common' ], function(common) {
        require([ 'app-folder/filename' ]);
    });
</script>
```

app-folder/filename.jsp is present in webapp folder. However, the js files at that location load with out a problem.

From log I can see only the following error

```
Exception occurred while authentication PWC6033 with jetty
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:149)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV.validate(JstlCoreTLV.java:105)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.validate(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:897)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateXmlView(Validator.java:1875)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1843)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:195)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:409)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:470)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:364)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:845)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
at com.apple.ist.crmpartner.esakuratool.external.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:523)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have no idea what this exception is and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

`PWC6033` is a generic compilation issue error code.

Knowing this code alone cannot help you fix your issue.

Look at the logs on the Jetty server side for other PWC error codes, those will tell you what specifically needs to be addressed to solve your issue.

If you cannot find these logs, you likely don't have java.util.logging setup to produce logging events that you need.

An alternate approach would be to use jspc to compile your JSP files during build time, (a recommended step) that should help you identify issues earlier, before you put your JSP into production.